# Remove middle 0 in string in R

Tags: r

I am trying to remove a zero within a string in R. I have a column in a frame that have to match with another, but one has a 0 one doesn't.
For instance,

A01 vs A1

It gets tricky when I have A10 ... A12.

I have searched, but can't figure out how to do this without copy and paste in the excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("A0", "A", c("A01", "A10"))
#[1] "A1"  "A10"
```

or to be more exact

```
sub("([A-Z])0(.*)", "\\1\\2", c("A01", "A10"))
#[1] "A1"  "A10"
```

Comment: The more exact one works because I have A1:G12. Perfect!